# How to export table data to file in postgresql using sql commands

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I am comparing the features of PostgreSQL and Greenplum. To access external files like flat files in Greenplum, externals tables are used.

1) To read a file and represent as table, Greenplum has readable external tables and we can achieve the same in PostgreSQL using foreign-data wrapper file_fdw

2) To load data from table into file greenplum has writable external tables. I need a way to achieve the same in PostgreSQL other than COPY commands or pg_dump. I need something like file_fdw so that I can use them as SQL commands and incorporate them in a function

Please advice

Comment: `COPY` is not psql command at all, its postgres extension to SQL - so it is SQL command

Comment: yeah sorry I will edit my question. I am looking for any other options available other than copy command

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you looking to replace PostgreSQL, or replace Greenplum Database, or use them together?

Comment: I have external tables in Greenplum. I wanted to know how I can use the same functionality in postgresql